# Error SCRIPT1002: Syntax error vendor.bundle.js (8315,1) , the line has eval function, loading angular 4 app in ie11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I have searched for the solution github and Stackoverflow but have not found any working solutions.
I have polyfills as recommended.
And it works in chrome but not in ie11.

Adding package.json. There are some external npm packages but do not know why it isn't working in IE

```
{
   "name": "webapp",
   "version": "0.2.6",
   "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "config": "ts-node ./config/set-env.ts",
      "start": "npm run config && ng serve",
      "build": "npm run config && ng build",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e",
      "i18n": "ng-xi18n"
     },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "^4.4.5",
      "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
      "@angular/common": "^4.4.5",
      "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.5",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.5",
      "@angular/core": "^4.4.5",
      "@angular/forms": "^4.4.5",
      "@angular/http": "^4.4.5",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.5",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.5",
      "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.4",
      "@angular/router": "^4.4.5",
      "@pa-util/angular2-idam": "^1.5.3",
      "@types/node": "^6.0.95",
      "angular2-logger": "^0.6.0",
      "array-unique": "^0.3.2",
      "bpmn-js": "^0.19.0",
      "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.11.2",
      "bulma": "^0.5.3",
      "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
      "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
      "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.3.0",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
      "jquery": "^3.2.1",
      "mydatepicker": "^2.6.2",
      "ng-gapi": "0.0.45",
      "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
      "ng2-pagination": "^2.0.2",
      "ng2-popover": "0.0.14",
      "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
      "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
      "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
      "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
      "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
   },
      "devDependencies": {
      "@angular/cli": "1.4.4",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
      "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
      "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
      "@types/jquery": "^3.2.15",
      "@types/node": "^6.0.90",
      "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
      "fs": "0.0.1-security",
      "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0", 
       "karma": "~1.7.0",
       "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
       "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
       "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
       "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
       "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
       "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
       "protractor": "~5.1.2",
       "ts-node": "^3.2.2",
       "tslint": "~5.7.0",
       "typescript": "~2.3.3",
       "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
       "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
       "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
       "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
       "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
       "less": "^2.7.2",
       "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
       "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
       "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
       "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
       "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
       "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
       "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5"
   }
}
```

Will keep on searching on github for the external packages used if there's an issue for execution of these in ie11

Adding an excerpt from the console 
Error on console 
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
vendor.bundle.js (8315,1)

```
eval("Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, \"__esModule\", { value: true 
 });\n/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, 
 \"Ng2MultiSelectDropDownModule\", function() { return 
 Ng2MultiSelectDropDownModule; });\n/* harmony export (binding) */ 
 __webpack_require__.d .............
```

Comment: Add this line in index.html file under HEAD tag. This may fix the issue.
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: Can you share your package.json file? This may be the dependecies version issue,

Comment: @MukeshKumar I have added the package json file.Please have a look.Thanks